# angular event capture parameter and call another method inline in the template

Tags: angular, events

In an angular template is it possible to capture the event parameter and call another method in the `.ts` file inline in the template itself.

I'm looking for something like this for a button event `click`.  `updateDetails` is a method in the `.ts` file.

```
(click)="(event)=>{updateDetails(event.target.value, 'otherParam')}"
```

However this does not work

Comment: Are you just looking for `(click)="updateDetails($event.target.value, 'otherParam')"`??

Comment: yes something like this, but this does not work, it does not pick up the first parameter properly, plus how does Angular know that $event is referring to the first parameter being emitted by source event itself?

Comment: It _does_ work. `$event` is a special template variable that Angular binds to whatever value is emitted by the event. Different events may emit different values. This is controlled by the component that raises the event but `$event` is bound to them. If you encounter difficulty getting `$event.target.value`, the `$event` emitted by that event might not have that property. Write a method and log it to see what it is.